# Accept multiple input types in ArcGIS Script Tools UI

Tags: arcpy, census

I'm working on a python script that calculates aggregations of ACS Variables (i.e. adding "Renters who spend more than 30% of Annual Income on Rent", "...40%...", "...50%...", etc.).  The tool tracks margin of error and also calculates normalized values for the aggregate total. I am using the script tool interface in ArcMap (right click a toolbox > add script > configure properties) to make a tool that has a GUI so that students who don't have scripting experience can use it with ease.

**Which data type I can choose for Input Dataset value so that the field accepts tables, shapefiles, or feature classes?** The ACS data they will be using can come in all three formats, and I don't want them to have to struggle with converting between data types or making joins (it's a very low-level GIS class).

[image: Screenshot of the Parameters Window]

**NOTES:**

- "Dataset" does not work because then the "Combine Fields" and "Normalize Field" boxes don't automatically populate with options for field types.
- I'm not even sure that what I want to accomplish is possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to set it to **Table View**. Feature Classes inherit from this interface. So setting the data type to Table View will allow you to see Feature Classes and standalone tables in the drop down.